# In Elixir, is there any way to get a module to list its functions?

Tags: elixir

In the same way that we can get any object (or class) in Ruby to list its methods, is there any function in Elixir to list all functions belonging to a module?  Something (at least remotely) like `String.functions` (where `String` could be replaced by any other module name)?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Each module in Elixir defines an `__info__` function you can call to get information about that module.

According the [Elixir Docs, 1.6.6 e.g.](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.6.6/Module.html#__info__/1), you can pass it `:functions` to get a list of functions that module contains.

```
Map.__info__(:functions)

[delete: 2, drop: 2, equal?: 2, fetch: 2, fetch!: 2, from_struct: 1, get: 2,
 get: 3, has_key?: 2, keys: 1, merge: 2, merge: 3, new: 0, pop: 2, pop: 3,
 put: 3, put_new: 3, size: 1, split: 2, take: 2, to_list: 1, update: 4,
 update!: 3, values: 1]
```

Comment: Update: changing my answer to use `:functions` instead of `:exports`. Both work, but `:functions` looks to be best choice, according the docs.

Comment: Is there also a way to get it in the order it was defined in the module? It's ordered alphabetically right now.

Answer (score 44):

Since Elixir is also Erlang, there is an Erlang way to do this as well.

Every Elixir and Erlang module has the function `module_info` defined at compile
time. There are two arities of this function. For example:

```
iex(1)> Atom.module_info
 [module: Atom,
 exports: [__info__: 1, to_string: 1, to_char_list: 1, module_info: 0,
 module_info: 1], attributes: [vsn:       [66271031909514292894123295368320335064]],
 compile: [options: [:debug_info], version: '6.0.1',
 time: {2015, 9, 29, 2, 34, 37},
 source: '/private/tmp/elixir20150928-10892-fvin6a/elixir-1.1.1/lib/elixir/lib/atom.ex'],
 native: false,
 md5: <<49, 219, 86, 35, 141, 153, 70, 174, 245, 100, 68, 5, 62, 231, 60, 216>>]
```

You can specify a specific attribute to return.

```
 iex(2)> Atom.module_info(:exports)
  [__info__: 1, to_string: 1, to_char_list: 1, module_info: 0, module_info: 1]
```

Erlang function verison:

```
iex(3)> :crypto.module_info(:exports)
 [version: 0, stop: 0, supports: 0, info_lib: 0, hash: 2, hash_init: 1,
 hash_update: 2, hash_final: 1, hmac: 3, hmac: 4, hmac_init: 2, hmac_update: 2,
 hmac_final: 1, hmac_final_n: 2, block_encrypt: 4, block_encrypt: 3,
 block_decrypt: 3, next_iv: 2, next_iv: 3, stream_init: 3, stream_init: 2,
 stream_encrypt: 2, stream_decrypt: 2, rand_bytes: 1, strong_rand_bytes: 1,
 rand_bytes: 3, rand_uniform: 2, rand_seed: 1, mod_pow: 3, verify: 5, sign: 4,
 public_encrypt: 4, private_decrypt: 4, private_encrypt: 4, public_decrypt: 4,
 exor: 2, generate_key: 2, generate_key: 3, compute_key: 4, md5: 1, md5_init: 0,
 md5_update: 2, md5_final: 1, md4: 1, md4_init: 0, md4_update: 2, md4_final: 1,
 sha: 1, sha_init: 0, sha_update: 2, ...]
```

This is what the IEx autocomplete function uses that allows you to expand both Elixir and Erlang functions.

Answer (score 18):

I've been using `iex(1)> exports TargetModuleName`. It lists all functions and macros belonging to a module. I stumbled onto it trying to figure out how to stop `Map.__info__(:functions)` from truncating a long function list.

Comment: Yes there are quite a few new longword commands in iex that don't show up in the default list of single char commands. It's worth poking around in the help for iex if you haven't done it in a while.

Answer (score 4):

Not a function but a way to get module to list its functions in `iex` is to write the name of the module followed by `.` then hiting tab:

```
iex(1)> IO.     ## Hit tab
ANSI                    Stream                  StreamError
binread/1               binread/2               binstream/2
binwrite/1              binwrite/2              chardata_to_string/1
getn/1                  getn/2                  getn/3
gets/1                  gets/2                  inspect/1
inspect/2               inspect/3               iodata_length/1
iodata_to_binary/1      puts/1                  puts/2
read/1                  read/2                  stream/2
warn/1                  warn/2                  write/1
write/2
```