# Check if Elixir module exports a specific function

Tags: elixir

How do you check if an `Elixir` module has exposed a specific public method? How do you check if the function has been exposed with a specific `arity`?

Doesn't work:

- `Map.methods`
- `Map.functions`
- `Map.has_function(:keys)`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Building on [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28664356/1533054) and [forum discussion here](https://elixirforum.com/t/how-to-check-if-a-module-exists-how-to-check-if-a-module-has-a-function/581/7), there are a few ways to do it:

---

## Check if Function exists for Module

You can check if the function name is present as a key in `Map.__info__(:functions)`

```elixir
module = Map
func   = :keys

Keyword.has_key?(module.__info__(:functions), func)
# => true
```

---

## Check if Function exists with specific arity

To check with `arity`, we can use [`Kernel.function_exported?/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#function_exported?/3):

```elixir
Kernel.function_exported?(Map, :keys, 1)         # => true
Kernel.function_exported?(Map, :keys, 2)         # => false
```

<sup>*Updated to use function from the Kernel module instead of the :erlang module*</sup>

Comment: `module.__info__` is sufficiently enough to check for a function with specific arity: `Map.__info__(:functions) |> Enum.filter(fn {k,_} -> k == :get end)
[get: 2, get: 3]`.

Comment: That's very similar to what I was actually doing. But that's the issue, it's too long. I like the built in erlang solution.

Comment: The only thing to watch out for is that if the function hasn't been called yet, it won't show up as exported if you use `Kernel.function_exported?` Maybe better to do `Keyword.get(Map.__info__(:functions), :keys) == 1`?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Kernel.function_exported?/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#function_exported?/3) like this:

```
function_exported?(List, :to_string, 1)
# => true
```

Answer (score 0):

In compile time one might use [`Module.defines?/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Module.html#defines?/2):

```
defmodule M do
  __MODULE__ |> Module.defines?({:keys, 1})
end
```

In runtime this will result in:

> ```
> Map |> Module.defines?({:keys, 1})
> ```
>
> > ** (ArgumentError) could not call `defines?` on module `Map` because it was already compiled
> >
> > ```
> > (elixir) lib/module.ex:1169: Module.assert_not_compiled!/2
> > (elixir) lib/module.ex:753: Module.defines?/2
> > ```

The shortest variant for runtime would be:

```
iex(59)> Map.__info__(:functions)[:get]           
#⇒ 2 # minimal arity, truthy
iex(60)> Map.__info__(:functions)[:nonexisting]
#⇒ nil # no such function, falsey
iex(61)> !!Map.__info__(:functions)[:get]      
#⇒ true # erlang style
iex(62)> !!Map.__info__(:functions)[:nonexisting]
#⇒ false # erlang style
```

Answer (score 0):

In Elixir Version `> 1.14`,

```
 Module.defines?(__MODULE__, {:version, 0}, :def) #=> true
```

where `:version` is your function name, `0` is the arity and `:def` is the kind.

see the [Elixir Reference here](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html#defines?/3)

Comment: This is a minor variant of @Aleksei's answer. It appears that the arity 3 version has been around since before 1.14 and simply allows you to query the function specifically by function type. This isn't new, and still only applies at compile time.